# Why does my file runs all te GOTO-commands?

Tags: batch-file

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this bat-file?
It works untill the 'if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0'

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq FortiClient.exe" > C:\Temp\FortiClient.txt
findstr.exe /L INFO C:\Temp\FortiClient.txt > c:\Temp\Info.txt
findstr /c:"INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria." c:\Temp\Info.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
GOTO install
) else (
GOTO leave
)
goto:eof
:install
    start E:\Forticlient_uninstall_install.bat
    timeout /t 90 /nobreak
    powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "& {Start-Process Powershell -ArgumentList ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File Messagebox.ps1' -verb RunAs}"
goto:eof
:leave
    exit
```

'''

Comment: put a `goto :eof` above each label (a label doesn't stop the code, it is just ignored)

Comment: And you should work on your `findstr` command. Currently it searches for lines that contain *any* of the words `INFO:`, `No`, `tasks`, `are`, etc. You'll need the `/c` switch. See `findstr /?` for details.

Comment: So like this?
'if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
GOTO install
goto:eof
) else (
GOTO leave
goto:eof
)'

Comment: not in the `goto` statements. I said above the `:labels`

Comment: My fault, so now I have it like this
'
goto:eof
:install
 start E:\Forticlient_uninstall_install.bat
 timeout /t 90 /nobreak
 powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "& {Start-Process Powershell -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File Messagebox.ps1' -verb RunAs}"
goto:eof
:leave
 exit
'

Comment: If I run the file now, he always set a More? before GOTO install

Comment: Can't verify. Your code copy-pasted on my system works (besides the `findstr` issue, I mentioned)

Comment: So it has to works with the things you told me that I have to change

Comment: yes, but it can be simplified - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't stop your subroutines, so after finishing the code in `install`, your script is just continuing with the next line (which is the label `:leave` and is ignored) and the next line, which is the next subroutine. Pit a `goto :eof` to stop the code execution, where you want to stop it (a label doesn't stop the execution)

This is how I would solve this task:

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq FortiClient.exe" | find "INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria." >nul
if ERRORLEVEL 1 exit /b
call E:\Forticlient_uninstall_install.bat
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "& {Start-Process Powershell -ArgumentList ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File Messagebox.ps1' -verb RunAs}"
```

No temporary files needed, just pass the output of `tasklist` to `find`.

no `else` clause needed by slightly rearranging the logic.

No `timeout` needed, because the install-script is called and not executed as separate (independent) process

More robust handling of ERRORLEVEL (see `if /?`)

using `find` instead of `findstr` (easier to use; your `findstr` solution looks for "one of those words" instead of "the complete string")

(To make your `findstr` work as intended, you have to use the `/c` switch: `findstr /m /c:"INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria."`)

Comment: Thank you, for your time. I will you your file because your file is much clearer and easier to use!

Comment: @SenneVroman, change the last line. If the PowerShell Script, _(`MessageBox.ps1`)_, is in the same directory as the batch file: `PowerShell "Start-Process -Verb RunAs PowerShell" "'-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File \"%~dp0Messagebox.ps1\"'"` or if the PowerShell script, _(`MessageBox.ps1`)_, is in your current directory, `PowerShell "Start-Process -Verb RunAs PowerShell" "'-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File \"%__CD__%Messagebox.ps1\"'"`.

Comment: …just to expand on that comment, first of all you don't need to change execution policy for any command, only for PowerShell scripts. Next, there is no need to use `& {scriptblock}`, and most importantly, because you are Running as administrator, the current directory will very likely change to `%SystemRoot%\System32`, which means that it will try to run a PowerShell script named `Messagebox.ps1` in the current directory. It is unlikely that you have specifically placed that file in that protected system location, so it will not be found, and will not therefore run.